# Auto suggestion in Commands in command line

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-arguments, autosuggest

I typed **git s** an pressed tab in ubuntu terminal and It shows git's sub-commands given below:

```
test: git s <tab>
shortlog  show  show-branch   stage stash status submodule
```

How is It happening? Auto suggestion for files is usual one. How can implement it for a command with subcommands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An introduction to bash completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316)

This will give you idea about auto completion in shells like Bash.